# Relative path vs absolute path in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I link my `CSS file` using `asset` provided by `Symfony2`.
So, I included it in my `layout.html.twig` as following:

`<link href="{{ asset('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">`

It worked on my computer, however, when I opened my website on mobile phone and my tablet.
The `CSS file` doesn't show up. I took half a day to find the problem, it drove me crazy. Finally, I found that it's because of the slash, "/", leading the path. So, I removed it:

`<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">`

It worked like a charm!

I did some research a little bit on this problem. Someone said that the correct path should not be leading by slash. However, why it does work on my computer but doesn't work on mobile?

**NOTE** The `CSS file` is stored in `web/bootstrap/css`.

In my opinion,

`asset('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')` and `asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')`

should finally return the same path, `web/bootstrap/css`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Nothing to do with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. It depends on if and how you have configured assetic, and specially the 'read_from' value ([see AsseticBundle-Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html)).

How does your assetic-section look like in your config.yml?

Let's say you have:

```
assetic:
    read_from: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
```

Now with this, if you use:

- asset('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
  This would result in a valid path: %kernel.root_dir%/../**web/bootstrap**/css/bootstrap.css
- asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
  This would result in an invalid path: %kernel.root_dir%/../**webbootstrap**/css/bootstrap.css

However, why it works on your computer and not on your mobile, I cannot say as too few information.